# rich text and xml content in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, user-interface, layout, unity-game-engine

I have an `xml` file that contains some survey questions, for example the following line that represents the title:

```
<title>Please describe how you feel now.</title>
```

The following simple code displays the above in my editor:

```
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal( displayStyle1 );
displayStyle1.fontSize = 20;
GUILayout.Label( Title, displayStyle1 );
GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

I decided to make the word NOW show in bold or perhaps underlined, so I inserted the following line in my code:

```
displayStyle1.richText = true;
```

and then changed the xml content to:

```
<title>Please describe how you feel <b>now</b>.</title>
```

But it is no making any difference. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `<title>` tag?

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for your reply. I need that tag to read in my pre-defined title; i.e. I have my own readFromXML and writeToXML functions, so title tags are necessary, but I guess my question is how can I enforce rich text styles within other xml tags? Or perhaps modifying my code?